# Passing a javascript variable to a php switch case statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, switch-statement

The javascript parameter "Step" should trigger a switch-case function in php. If Step is one than trigger this piece of code in php and return the output by JSON.

If I take a look in firebug the post string is: `Step=one&inputFname=rick&inputLname=bovenkamp` I think this is correct. So the problem must be in the php file and I think it's in the `$_POST` part...

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very great!

javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#userForm").submit(function() {
        var inputFname = $('#inputFname').attr('value');
        var inputLname = $('#inputLname').attr('value');
            var Step = "one";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "main.php",
            data: {Step: Step,inputFname: inputFname,inputLname: inputLname},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                $("p.succesText").html(data.jsCode);
                    $("form#userForm").hide();
                $("div.success").fadeIn();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                $("form#userForm").hide();
                $("p.errorHead").html("Something went wrong.");
                $("p.errorText").text("ResponseText: " + xhr.responseText
                                        + "Statuscode: " + xhr.status
                                        + "ReadyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                $("div.error").fadeIn();
            }
        });
            return false;
    });
});
```

PHP file:

```php
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $log = array();

    $varStep = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["Step"]));  

    switch($varStep) {

        case "one":

        $varFname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputFname"]);
        $varLname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputLname"]);

        //Make Database connection
        $db = mysql_connect("192.168.178.254","root","852456");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("Ajax" ,$db);

        //Generate code and check if code already exists in the database
        do
        {
            $varCode = rand(10000, 99999);
            $dbCheckCode = "";
            $dbCheckCode = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TableAjax WHERE code='$varCode'");
        }
        while (mysql_fetch_array($dbCheckCode) !== false);

        //Save the Form data in the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO TableAjax (fname, lname, code) VALUES (".PrepSQL($varFname) . ", " .PrepSQL($varLname) . ", " .PrepSQL($varCode) . ")";
        mysql_query($sql);  

        //Return code to frontend
        $log['jsCode'] = $varCode;

        break;
    }

    echo json_encode($log);


    //Clean SQL statement
    function PrepSQL($value)
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
        return($value);
    }   

?>
```

Comment: have you checked what value(**step**) php receives ?

Comment: I would recommend changing your mysql login data right away as posting it on a web-site is not a good idea.

Comment: @Jeroen Don't worry that's fake data. Thanks by the way ;-)

Comment: Have you tested the php without using ajax using a normal form post? You can enable error displaying using `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` at the top of your script, add error handling for all database calls and see what it displays.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I tried it without ajax and going directly to the url http ://192.168.178.254/test/main.php?Step=one&inputFname=Sjaakie&inputLname=Hoek Without success unfortunately It returns an empty []

Comment: @Rick van den Bovenkamp That's because you need to `POST` the form, if you just enter a query string, the values will be stored in `$_GET` and not in `$_POST`.

Comment: When adding the ini_set i see the error 

<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  Step in <b>/share/MD0_DATA/Web/test/main.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Step in quotes `data : {"Step" : Step,...`.

You are passing the value of the variable as the key in that case, that is to say you are actually passing `data : {"one" : "one",...`.  You should do the same with `inputLname` and `inputFname`.

**Edit - Explanation**

If you look at what the contentType options does here at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, you will see that the default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is what you want.  Essentially what your PHP error was indicating is that the `$_POST` array was empty because it did not know how to read your data due to the format.  You want your return data to be `json`, the `dataType` option was all you needed.

You still would have needed to do what I indicated in the first part of the post, but essentially you had two errors that were tripping you up.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: My new data string is: data: {"Step": Step,"inputFname": inputFname,"inputLname": inputLname}, Unfortunately it gives me the same error Undefined index: Step in /share/MD0_DATA/Web/test/main.php on line 6

Comment: Line 6 is by the way varStep = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["Step"])); but I can't figure out what's wrong with that code.

Comment: Try removing contentType and dataType from the JS.  If that doesnt work, if you have firebug installed can you post the header info?

Comment: Thanks marteljn, removing contentype did the trick! :-) Do you have an explaination?

Comment: I posted an explanation as an edit.  I hope that makes sense.